# What are the benefits of using Azure Service Connector to connect an App Service with an SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a .NET app deployed as a Web App App Service on Azure. I connect from the app with two Azure SQL Databases in the same Resource Group.

For one of them, I have created a connection with the App service by Service Connector and for the other I wrote the connection string from hand. Both connection seem to work just fine.

*My questions are*: What can Service Connector do for me? Does it maybe allow me to get rid of having to add the IP of my app as a server firewall rule?

I read quite a bit of Microsoft documentation and didn't find a description of the actual benefits.

Answer (score 0):

> What can Service Connector do for me?

- `Service Connector` makes easy and simple to establish and maintain connections between services.
- `Service Connectors` helps us to connect multiple servers together.
- We can use service Connector either from `Azure Portal` , Azure CLI or even from Visual Studio to create connections.
- It is like an Extension Resource provider which reduces the `manual configuration` and maintenance difficulties.

***From Visual Studio***

Right click on the `Project folder` => `Add` => `Connected Service`

[image]

`Add a service dependency` => search for `Azure SQL Database` and select => click on next => select the DB, create one if you don't have and continue with next steps.

- It provides an option to store Connection string in `Azure Key Vault`.

[image]

***From Azure App Service***
[image]

> Does it maybe allow me to get rid of having to add the IP of my app as a server firewall rule?

- `Service connector` reduces the manual configuration. It will enable the permission for us to make the connection and configures the network settings.
- If service connector detects that we are using firewall in our application, it keeps IP of our Compute Service into the allowed list.